# Subprocess popen second instance of Kivy gives module import error

Tags: python, kivy

I'm trying to run two instances of Kivy. I know you're not supposed to try and open a second window as per the docs but I need a second window, can't do without. It's either open up a second window or bail on Kivy.

Given that every Python GUI library I've looked into has a less than appealing aesthetic I'd much prefer to stick with Kivy. Feel free to correct me if I'm wrong.

Here's the issue. I can't get the second app file to open. It gets caught at line 1 importing Kivy.

```
### call to popen from main.py
class RefreshButton(Button):
    pass
    def launchChild(self):
        import subprocess
        subprocess.Popen('python test.py', shell=True)

    def on_press(self):
        self.launchChild()

### test.py
from kivy.app import App  ### <- Line 1 ImportError: No module named kivy.app
from kivy.uix.button import Button

class MainApp(App):
    def build(self):
        b = Button(text='Test')
        return b


if __name__ == '__main__':
    MainApp().run()
```

Comment: Are you sure it is not because of Button? What is the full traceback? `import Button, Button, Button`? Do you really like Buttons?

Comment: @PadraicCunningham No, it's coming from the test.py file. Main.py opens/runs fine, the button does what it's supposed to. The exact error is `Line 1 ImportError: No module named kivy.app`.

Comment: How do you launch Main.py? As in how do you run the method that it calls the process? The issue is most like because python points to a different interpreter than the one you have kivy installed for

Comment: Hm, that's interesting. I'm just launching from an IDE right now. The button is just a simple test button in the main.py app.

Comment: Then almost 100 percent python is referring to another interpreter than the one you are using in your ide.  Is `test.py` referring to the top or bottom code?

Comment: What version of python are you using in the ide?

Comment: 3.4.2, in Library/Frameworks. I'm pretty positive you're right. How do you change which interpreter the OS points to when opening .py files?

Comment: Ok, to solve the mystery for sure use `python3`

Comment: Got it. That worked If you answer the question I'll accept it. This line `subprocess.Popen('python3 test.py', shell=True)` just needed a 3 added to python.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per the comments there is a mismatch between the python  interpreter you are using in your IDE, which is *python3.4* and what interpreter *python* refers to in your *subprocess* call which is most likely python2. To solve it you just need to specify to use the python3 interpreter, you also don't need *shell=True*, you can just pass a list of args:

```
 subprocess.Popen(['python3',  'test.py'])
```